# Redis streams publisher can't find command XADD

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data

I got few errors from redis streams first is:

```
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException: Error in execution; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR unknown command 'XREADGROUP'
```

and the second is when I try to create stream publisher but I got error

```
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException: Error in execution; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR unknown command 'XADD'
```

my function for publish data is really simple

```
public void test1(){
        ObjectRecord<String, String> keyStream = StreamRecords.newRecord()
                .ofObject(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .withStreamKey("keyStream");
        redisTemplate.opsForStream()
                .add(keyStream);

    }
```

But on function add this error ocurse. And If anybody can help me with this problem please let me know, thanks

Comment: Streams were added in Redis v5 - I'm betting my kids' college saving plans that your Redis server's version is lower ;)

Answer (score 2):

In the console,run

```
redis-server --version
```

And you can check the redis version. Redis stream is only supported with Redis version > 5

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem

```
redis-server --version

Redis server v=6.2.3 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-5.1.0 bits=64 build=a0976c4a01bcd8ee
```

UPD: my problem was solved of downgrading redis to version 5.0.12